# Ubuntu 18.04.4 VM running on Surface Pro 7 through Oracle Virtual Box Type Cover Keyboard not working

Tags: keyboard, virtualbox, oracle, surface

I'm trying to run Ubuntu 18.04.4 as a VM through Oracle VirtualBox on my Surface Pro 7.  Virtual Box installed fine and Ubuntu installs fine up to when you have to enter account info to finish setup.  It won't except any input from my Type Cover Keyboard.  I tried to remove the Type Cover and use a USB keyboard but that doesn't work either.  I tried the soft keyboard and can't get that to work.  I can right click on the field and it'll let me inset emoji, which is useless but I thought was interesting.

Comment: USB devices won't work on a Guest OS until you change you VirtualBox settings on the Host OS.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  It didn't work but it seems the issue was actually that I was using a wireless USB dongle.  A friend of mine suggested switching to a wired USB mouse and keyboard and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Then that was the problem - VBox setting will pass USB plain mouse/keyboard by default, but not most other dongles.